# How to concatenate lxml string with another string in Python

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

connection = urllib.urlopen('http://example.com')
dom = lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())

for link in dom.xpath('//div[@id="right-column"]//a/@href'):
    print link
```

My problem is that each `link` from that `for loop` does not contain the entire path of the link but only what comes after `http://example.com`.

Example of link variable:

```
/andrew-darius-et-al-mob-app-maker  
/andrew-darius-et-al-explaindio-3-0
```

Now, what I would like to do, is concatenating `connection` and `link` in that `for` loop so that I will have a full path:

```
http://example.com/andrew-darius-et-al-mob-app-maker  
http://example.com/andrew-darius-et-al-explaindio-3-0
```

---

EDIT 1:

```
 import urllib
 import lxml.html
 from urlparse import urljoin

 URL = urllib.urlopen('http://muncheye.com')
 dom = lxml.html.fromstring(URL.read())

 for link in dom.xpath('//div[@id="right-column"]//a/@href'):
     FINAL_URL = urljoin('http://muncheye.com', link)
     print FINAL_URL
```

Comment: What's wrong with `print 'http://example.com' + link`?

Comment: The safe way to do that is to use [urlparse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin)

Comment: @ParkerHoyes I don't know how safe it is to reuse that string again

Comment: If you are worried about redirects, you can use `connection.geturl()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `urljoin` to make the URLs absolute. You have to know, that HTML-Files can set their base url with the base-tag. So i considered that also:

```
import urlparse
import lxml.html

URL = 'http://example.com'
dom = lxml.html.parse(URL)
url = dom.docinfo.URL
base = dom.find('head/base')
if base:
    url = base.get('href', url)

for link in dom.xpath('//div[@id="right-column"]//a/@href'):
    print urlparse.urljoin(url, link)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. What about the edit that I've made ? would that also be a good solution ?